# Image Inside Scroll Rect is positioning in Game Mode

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollrect

I am facing a problem with the position of the image inside the scroll Rect. When I am in game mode the position is automatically changing. So the image is automatically filling in the Scroll Rect. I need it to be in the bottom. Thanks

Normal Mode:

[image]

Game Mode:

[image]

And the Scroll Rect:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? do you really need to place it as child of scroll rect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `Movement Type` to `Unrestricted` in the inspector. Yours is set to `Elastic` which is what will bounce your content back into view.